# Поворот текста на Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, html5-canvas

Есть Canvas, на котором отрисовывается изображение. 
На изображение можно накладывать текст. Можно выбирать угол наклона текста. 
Изображение можно перемещать по канвасу. 
Суть в том, что перемещение изображения работает нормально, но текст должен перемещаться вместе с ним. Однако, так как canvas.context в момент отрисовки текста под углом повернут, оси x и y для текста получаются смещенными. То есть, если повернуть текст на 90 градусов, а потом потянуть картинку вниз/вверх, то текст уедет вправо/влево.

Как можно это исправить? Чтобы текст перемещался вместе с картинкой?

Отрисовка изображения:

```
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, viewportOffsetX, viewportOffsetY, img.width, img.height);
```

Отрисовка текста поверх изображения:

```
    ctx.save();
    var offsetX = textObj.x;
    var offsetY = textObj.y;

    ctx.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
    ctx.rotate(textObj.rotation);
    ctx.translate(-offsetX, -offsetY);
    ctx.font = textObj.fontSize + 'px ' + textObj.font;
    ctx.fillStyle = textObj.color;

    ctx.fillText(textObj.text, textObj.x, textObj.y);
    textObj.x -= viewportOffsetX;
    textObj.y -= viewportOffsetY;

    ctx.restore();
```

Изменение viewportOffsetX/viewportOffsetY происходит при драге в mousemove.

```
viewportOffsetX += deltaX; // смещение по X
viewportOffsetY += deltaY; // смещение по Y
```

```js
var textInput = null;
var canvasImage = null;
var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;

var renderingInterval = null;
var textComponents = [];

var scale = 1;
var viewportOffsetX = 0;
var viewportOffsetY = 0;
var drag = false;
var img = null;

var text = null;
var font = 'arial';
var fontSize = 20;
var color = '#000';
var textRotation = 0;

var originX = 0;
var originY = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
 img = new Image();
  img.src = "http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Cat-flehmen-response.jpg";
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  textComponents.push({text: 'Test', x: 0, y: 0, saved: true, font: 'arial', fontSize: 30, color: 'red', rotation: Math.PI / 2});
  
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', onMouseDown);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
  
  img.onload = function(){
    renderTextCanvas();
  };
});

function renderTextCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    ctx.scale(scale, scale);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, viewportOffsetX, viewportOffsetY, img.width, img.height);

    textComponents.forEach(function (textObj) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.font = textObj.fontSize + 'px ' + textObj.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = textObj.color;
        ctx.rotate(textObj.rotation);
        if (textObj.saved) {
            ctx.fillText(textObj.text, textObj.x + viewportOffsetX, textObj.y + viewportOffsetY);
        }
        else {
            ctx.fillText(textObj.text, textObj.x, textObj.y);
            textObj.saved = true;
            textObj.x -= viewportOffsetX;
            textObj.y -= viewportOffsetY;
        }
        ctx.restore();
    });

}

    function onMouseUp(e) {
        drag = false;
    }

    function onMouseDown(event) {
        originX = event.pageX;
        originY = event.pageY;

        if (event.touches) {
            var touches = event.touches[0];
            originX = touches.pageX;
            originY = touches.pageY;
        }

        if (textInput) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = originX - rect.left;
            var y = originY - rect.top;
            registerTextComponent(textInput, x, y);
            textInput = null;
            return;
        }
        drag = true;
    }


    function onMouseMove(e) {
        if (drag) {
            var pageX = e.pageX;
            var pageY = e.pageY;

            if (e.touches) {
                var touches = e.touches[0];
                pageX = touches.pageX;
                pageY = touches.pageY;
            }

            var deltaX = pageX - originX;
            var deltaY = pageY - originY;

            if (Math.abs(viewportOffsetX) < Math.abs(img.width / 2)) {
                viewportOffsetX += deltaX;
            }
            else {
                if (viewportOffsetX < 0) {
                    viewportOffsetX += 1;
                }
                else {
                    viewportOffsetX -= 1;
                }
            }
            if (Math.abs(viewportOffsetY) < Math.abs(img.height / 2)) {
                viewportOffsetY += deltaY;
            }
            else {
                if (viewportOffsetY < 0) {
                    viewportOffsetY += 1;
                }
                else {
                    viewportOffsetY -= 1;
                }
            }
            originX = pageX;
            originY = pageY;
            renderTextCanvas();
        }
    }
```

```css
#canvas{
  background: #ffe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas width = "600" height = "400" id = "canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: [mcve] сделай в сниппете.

Comment: Готово. Обновил пост.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь нужно пересчитывать координаты для текста с использованием матрицы поворота в двухмерном пространстве.

```js
var textInput = null;
var canvasImage = null;
var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;

var renderingInterval = null;
var textComponents = [];

var scale = 1;
var viewportOffsetX = 0;
var viewportOffsetY = 0;
var drag = false;
var img = null;

var text = null;
var font = 'arial';
var fontSize = 20;
var color = '#000';
var textRotation = 0;

var originX = 0;
var originY = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  img = new Image();
  img.src = "http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Cat-flehmen-response.jpg";
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  textComponents.push({
    text: 'Test',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    saved: true,
    font: 'arial',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'red',
    rotation: Math.PI / 2
  });

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', onMouseDown);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);

  img.onload = function() {
    renderTextCanvas();
  };
});

function renderTextCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, viewportOffsetX, viewportOffsetY, img.width, img.height);

  textComponents.forEach(function(textObj) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = textObj.fontSize + 'px ' + textObj.font;
    ctx.fillStyle = textObj.color;
    ctx.rotate(textObj.rotation);
    if (textObj.saved) {
      //!!!!
      var x = viewportOffsetX * Math.cos(textObj.rotation) + viewportOffsetY * Math.sin(textObj.rotation);
      var y = -viewportOffsetX * Math.sin(textObj.rotation) + viewportOffsetY * Math.cos(textObj.rotation);
      ctx.fillText(textObj.text, textObj.x + x, textObj.y + y);
    } else {
      ctx.fillText(textObj.text, textObj.x, textObj.y);
      textObj.saved = true;
      textObj.x -= viewportOffsetX;
      textObj.y -= viewportOffsetY;
    }
    ctx.restore();
  });

}

function onMouseUp(e) {
  drag = false;
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  originX = event.pageX;
  originY = event.pageY;

  if (event.touches) {
    var touches = event.touches[0];
    originX = touches.pageX;
    originY = touches.pageY;
  }

  if (textInput) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = originX - rect.left;
    var y = originY - rect.top;
    registerTextComponent(textInput, x, y);
    textInput = null;
    return;
  }
  drag = true;
}


function onMouseMove(e) {
  if (drag) {
    var pageX = e.pageX;
    var pageY = e.pageY;

    if (e.touches) {
      var touches = e.touches[0];
      pageX = touches.pageX;
      pageY = touches.pageY;
    }

    var deltaX = pageX - originX;
    var deltaY = pageY - originY;

    if (Math.abs(viewportOffsetX) < Math.abs(img.width / 2)) {
      viewportOffsetX += deltaX;
    } else {
      if (viewportOffsetX < 0) {
        viewportOffsetX += 1;
      } else {
        viewportOffsetX -= 1;
      }
    }
    if (Math.abs(viewportOffsetY) < Math.abs(img.height / 2)) {
      viewportOffsetY += deltaY;
    } else {
      if (viewportOffsetY < 0) {
        viewportOffsetY += 1;
      } else {
        viewportOffsetY -= 1;
      }
    }
    originX = pageX;
    originY = pageY;
    renderTextCanvas();
  }
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  background: #ffe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas width="600" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>
```